# Grouping with autoincrement serial number Sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have attached a Image with my problem  please Help me....[image]

Comment: The question in an image??? That is useless for anyone else searching this site. Please put some effort in asking. What have you tried so far? What errors did you get?

Comment: It doesn't show any effort to solve the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Use Ranking Functions](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/09/sql-server-2005-sample-example-of-ranking-functions-row_number-rank-dense_rank-ntile/)**

```
select *,row_number() over(partition by Test_ID order by Test_id) as [#no]
from table_name
```

If column **[#no]** is already present in Table, and if you want to **update** it than use the below Query

Treating **`Group_Id`** as Primary key

```
update t1
set t1.[#no]=t2.[#no]
from table_name t1
inner join 
(select Group_Id,row_number() over(partition by Test_ID order by Test_id) as [#no]
from table_name)t2 on t1.Group_Id=t2.Group_Id
```

Comment: "," is necessary after "*"??

Comment: You'll need an [ORDER BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) as well. (Not test_id - group id or name)

Comment: @luv: Its showing "The ranking function "row_number" must have an ORDER BY clause"